# change div display while checkbox checked in gridview using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have `gridview`that binded to database. There is `checkbox` in it that I want change `display` attribute of another `div` with `checkbox` checked value.
This is my back-end code in asp.net, but it isn't work! What can I do to solve it?

```
protected void gv_sourceGalleryPic_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "checkPic")
    {
        CheckBox chkItem = (CheckBox)gv_sourceGalleryPic.FindControl("ck_checkGalleryPic_copyMove");

        if (chkItem.Checked == true)
        {
            div1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define "not working". Does the checkbox loses it's state? Is there an error? Does the div remain hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `OnCheckedChanged` event for `checkbox` instead `onRowCommand` like this:

**Markup**

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv_sourceGalleryPic">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ck_checkGalleryPic_copyMove" runat="server"
            OnCheckedChanged="chkBox_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code behind**

```
protected void chkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chk = sender as CheckBox;

        if (chk.Checked)
        {
            div1.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Display, "block");
        }           
    }
```

Comment: As a matter of fact, in this cases it would be better run client-side.

Comment: @jh_6990 Please upvote this answer if it helps you, so people know this is the correct answer and helps them.

Answer (score 1):

As i know, Asp.Net CheckBoxes do not have attributes named `CommandName` and `CommandArgument`. Therefore you can not use `RowCommand` event which is going to be fired when you change checked.
You should use some simple javascript codes instead of it like example code below:

```
function hidediv(chk) {
        var element = document.getElementById("div1");
        if (chk.checked) 
        { element.style.display = 'none'; }
    }
```

And then fire this function on change event of all checkboxes like this:

```
onchange="hidediv(this);"
```

By the way, if you want to change display a div section only, it would be better to use html input tag instead of asp.net checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find Div

```
HtmlGenericControl div1= (HtmlGenericControl )gv_sourceGalleryPic.FindControl("div1");
```